# add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail') doesnt call/hook my function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to post data from one of our Contact7 forms then save that data in table of mysql. I am very new for WordPress. I followed other people's code. But I have no luck to receive data in my table. I feel add_action-wpcf7_before_send_mail  cant hook my function because I wrote wrong spelled or missed code inside of my function to test if it works. But no error shows when i submit data from my wordpress form. Below is my code, please comment anything that might help. Thank you!

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','contactform7_before_send_mail',1);

function contactform7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) {       
  $wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true;
  global $wpdb;   
  $title = $contact_form->title();   

  $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
  if ( $submission ) {
    $formData = $submission->get_posted_data();     
  }

  if ( 'Membership-2' == $title ) {   
    $name = $formData['your-name'];     
    $email = $formData['your-email'];   
    $company = $formData['your-company'];   
    $title = $formData['your-title'];   
    $location = $formData['your-location']; 
  }

  $wpdb->insert('aoe84i5nxf_member_info', array('id' => null,'name' => $name,'email' => $email,'company' => $company,'title' => $title, 'location' => $location), array(null,'%s','%s','%s','%s','%d') ); 
}
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
```

Comment: you have `remove_all_filters` at the end, it removes what you add to the hook. To save form values, have you tried the plugin Flamingo ? https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/

Comment: Thank you very much, yes it works now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','contactform7_before_send_mail',1);

function contactform7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) {       

    if ( !isset($contact_form->posted_data) && class_exists('WPCF7_Submission') ) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $submission ) {
            $formData = $submission->get_posted_data();     
        }
    } else {
        // We can't retrieve the form data
        return $contact_form;
    }

    if ( 'Membership-2' == $contact_form->title() ) {   
        $contact_form->skip_mail = true;

        $name = $formData['your-name'];     
        $email = $formData['your-email'];   
        $company = $formData['your-company'];   
        $title = $formData['your-title'];   
        $location = $formData['your-location']; 

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert('aoe84i5nxf_member_info', array('id' => null,'name' => $name,'email' => $email,'company' => $company,'title' => $title, 'location' => $location), array(null,'%s','%s','%s','%s','%d') ); 
    }

    return $contact_form;

}
```

which makes a few changes to your code:

1. Checks whether we can retrieve the form submission data.
2. Corrects some of the form data object variable names ($wpcf7_data).
3. Makes sure the skip_mail and database insert only occur for the Membership-2 form submissions.
4. Removes the remove_all_filters line - this would simply unhook your custom function, so it would never run.